# Finding the maximum and minimum sum of all but 1 integer(s) in a given array

Tags: c, data-structures

Today I'm here with another problem to solve.

It's one from the HackerRank assignments, https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem
So, the general idea is to find the minimum-sum and maximum-sum of 4/5 integers from a given array;

In order to crack this, I came up with using a sorting algorithm to first sort the array in ascending order, post which I shall add all integers except the last one to find the Minimum-Sum and adding all integers except the first one to find the Maximum-Sum.

```
void miniMaxSum(int arr_count, int* arr) {

    int i,j,min,temp;
    for(i=0;i<arr_count-1;i++)
    {
        min=i;
        for(j=i+1;j<arr_count;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j]<arr[min])
                min=j;
        }
        temp=arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[min];
        arr[min]=temp;
    }

    int minsum=0,maxsum=0;
    for(i=0;i<arr_count-1;i++)
        minsum+=arr[i];
    for(i=1;i<arr_count;i++)
        maxsum+=arr[i];

    printf("%d %d",minsum,maxsum);
}
```

The following code works for a few test cases but doesn't work for them all. Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: what if all values are negative??? you must sum all for getting the minimum sum???

Comment: Negative/Positive doesn't matter I suppose, Because the min-sum and max-sum would work either way.

Comment: There's a hint on the problem that you should read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to sort the array in order to get the results.
What you need is simply know what is the maximum and minimum value of the array.
Just use a single loop.

```
void miniMaxSum(int arr_count, int* arr) {
    int i,min, max;
    min = max = arr[0];
    for(i=1;i<arr_count;i++)
    {
        if(min > arr[i]) min = arr[i];
        else if(max < arr[i]) max = arr[i];
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for(i=0;i<arr_count;i++)
        sum+=arr[i];

    printf("%d %d",sum-max,sum-min);
}
```

HTH

Comment: Your code to “use a single loop” contains two loops.

Comment: I was refering to a "nested" loops.

Comment: Nonetheless, the problem can be solved with a single loop, and that is preferable because it brings the data into cache just once, as well as avoiding loop overhead.

Comment: I think your solution is an enhanced one that's all, the problem i'm facing is when the numbers are huge, the test cases fail, which is leading me to believe that I should be working on the issue with a long/double data type.

Comment: I saw your original code and think is fine, If you can send one error example case, I can help you more. I do not think is the precision.